# Android Studio error gradle sync issues after update into 3.3.2

Tags: android-studio

Hello I have a problem I upgraded my android studio into android 3.3.2. When I opend my old project it was syncing and at the end it gives me errors like this:

```
ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'BreatherApp' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.30
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript { 
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11' 

    repositories { 
        google() 
        jcenter() 
    } 

    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2' 
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.11" 

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong 
        // in the individual module build.gradle files 
    } 
} 

allprojects { 
    repositories { 
        google() 
        jcenter() 
    } 
} 

task clean(type: Delete) { 
    delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

Please help me I  have search things to do but its still not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The error log already tells you:

   > The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version **1.3.0** and higher

   but you have

   > root project 'BreatherApp' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:**1.2.71**

   Then you just need to update your Kotlin version, which is one line inside `build.gradle` **inside your 'BreatherApp' module**, to a `1.3.0` or newer version.
2. The error log already tells you:

   > Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.30

   There [is no `1.3.30` of `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.30), but a list of [`1.3.30-dev-xxxx` and `1.3.30-eap-xx`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7?repo=kotlin-dev). Choose the version you need (maybe `1.3.11` as your root `build.gradle` said), edit the **module** `build.gradle`.

**Update**: Please clarify **project** `build.gradle` and **module** `build.gradle`